# How to add iPhone to my product list if it's already registered to another apple ID?

Tags: iphone, serial-number

How to add my telephone serial number, if it's already registered on another ID? I got this phone in exchange for my broken previous one in tech. service, so I think that it was used by someone and registered early.

Comment: I'd guess you'd have to talk to Apple. They'd want to see proof it's yours, no doubt.

Comment: Yes, more than a year. Only problem - how to do that, I live outside US...

Comment: Try your nearest number - http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201232 or go to an Apple Store, if there's one near you.

Comment: Unfortunately calls are too expensive for me in this case and there isn't any Apple Stores in my country. It is a pity that they do not have online support.

Comment: Just Google "apple iphone customer service contact" I'm in the uk so I get https://www.apple.com/uk/support/iphone/contact/ If you know the country code for your nearest support centre you could try replacing it in that URL

Comment: Thanks, only that I find - with that issue I need to phone them by myself, because the tech. support is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, an iPhone is linked to an Apple ID until it is released by the owner or by Apple techs (like when your phone is traded for a new one, rather than being repaired and returned to you).

This is intended to prevent theft; you can't just take someone's phone because they have to release it from their Apple ID first. If they don't, the phone will be very trackable by the owner of that Apple ID, the phone can't be reset without the owner's Apple ID & Password, and you can't get any new apps or anything because you won't have the Apple ID & password to enter for a purchase or to enter in order to remove the Apple ID from the phone.

If you got this phone legitimately, you'll have to contact the "tech. service" you used and ask them what they'll do to fix the issue. They may be able to take it back, and, as an authorized Apple repair center, send it to Apple to have the Apple ID cleared. I'm not sure they would or could do that.

There's nothing a user can do to release a phone without the original Apple ID & password, and this is intentional. If Apple set up 'online support' and allowed any user to release any phone from the Apple ID associated with it, then it would be much easier to steal and sell iPhones.

...again, as far as I know... ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed response. Just tried to call customer service, but have not been able to reach any result. Only lost money for call! Don't know what to do now.